# How to extract current login user?

Tags: php, jenkins

I have created a project in PHP (PHP API master) using an `<iframe>` in the description window inside Jenkins and I need to determine the currently logged in user.

Is this possible? How can I extract the logged in users user id?

Now I can extract jobs and views:

```
echo '<br><br>Jobs:';
$view = $jenkins->getView('All');

foreach ($view->getJobs() as $job) {
    echo '<br>' . $job->getName();
}
```

Is there a similar function for users?

Comment: Are you only looking for a function or will it work if available as Jenkins env variable?

Comment: I need to extract login and pass it to another function.

Comment: Check this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14605

Comment: Nope - it's not working :(

Comment: Did you go through the comment by some user Jesse Glick in the above link?